# Still a temp in the company but my job position changed

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, position

I'm still a temp in the company, but my job position changed. I started as a packer for 2 months but then my position changed to be a machine operator. I have been a machine operator for at least 3 months but today I just realized that I'm still getting paid per hour from my position as a packer.

So do I call the temp agency and let them know that my position changed so I can get paid per hour as an operator? If so, what should I say?

Comment: You have to let your agency know ASAP that you have been a machine operator for the last three months, and you have to say "And I'd like to point out that the hourly rate for a machine operator is higher than the hourly rate for a packer" - Be self-assured: you are not begging for a favor, you are asking for fair treatment and that means in this case, fair pay for fair work. If your agency charges more for a machine operator than for a packer, it's out of $$, too. Because it's not charging money that it could have charged.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan - shouldn't these be answers instead of comments?

Answer (score 3):

I would contact your representative with your agency and make sure that they are aware that you have the new position.  I would then follow up with a question about any feedback they had provided.

Assuming the feedback was good that is the best time to ask the question to find out if the pay rate is different now that you are an operator.  It is completely possible that they "forgot" to change your pay rate.  If that is the case then after you get confirmation that your rate either will be or has been adjusted I would also ask the question about back pay.

It is also possible that they have a blanket rate that they charge for all of the staff that they provide.  If that is the case, and you have good feedback, then there is no harm in asking if based on your performance you could get an increase in pay.  As long as you ask it as a question and do not try to make it sound like an ultimatum the worst they say is no sorry we cant.  And it might result in a raise.

Ideally if they change your position like this it is best to communicate with your agency right away.  Find out if this is the same rate of pay, and if their are increased risks and responsibilities with the new position, I would expect some sort of increase in compensation.  But asking when it happens is very reasonable even if the answer is no you don't get a bump in pay.